# Dockerコンテナ上のMySQLサーバーに接続できない

Tags: mysql, docker

DockerコンテナのMySQLサーバに同じアクセスできません
コンテナ上のMySQLに同じホスト上の別のコンテナにあるubuntuからアクセスしようとしていますが、`mysql -u root -p`と実行して、正しいパスワードを入力しても
`Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`
というエラーが発生します
MySQLのイメージはDockerHubから`mysql:latest`でとってきたものです

Docker for Mac Beta 1.12.0-rc3-beta18を使っています

docker-compose_db.yml(dbの部分):

```
 db:
     build: 
         context: .
             dockerfile: "mysqlfile"
         environment:
             - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
         ports:
             - "3306:3306"
         volumes:
             - ./mysql:/mysql
```

mysqlfile (dockerfile)

```
from mysql:latest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL は `-h` オプションを指定しない限りはローカルホストの MySQL デーモンに接続しようとします。ホストが同じコンテナであっても、コンテナの中からは別コンテナは別マシンとして認識されます。

質問文の通りの `docker-compose_db.yml` であれば、MySQL クライアントを動かすコンテナでは MySQL サーバは `build` で名前解決されるはずなので、`mysql -u root -p -h build` のようにして接続できないでしょうか?